# Reducing lines in methods of Python class to manage tweets

Tags: python

How could I reduce the length of my functions restricting them to max 10 lines?
Other comments are welcome on the code in general.

```
import config_files
import math
from datetime import datetime
import importlib
import sys
from scan_twittosphere import *
from tweets import *
import nltk
debugger = importlib.import_module('config_files.debugger')

"""
Performs operations of allocating lr users to pertinent tweets and users and sending the result back
to create_json object
"""
class filter_tweets:
    """
    method: constructor
    input: 
            String: lr user screen name
            String List: List of user keywords
            Object: Twitter api connection object
            Object: Config file object
            Integer: User Autofavorite mode
            String: environment of execution
    output: None
    """

    def __init__(self,screen_name, keywords, api, config,mode_auto_favorite, env):
        self.screen_name = screen_name
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.api = api
        self.config = config
        self.mode_auto_favorite = mode_auto_favorite
        self.MongoObj = MongodbConnections(env)
        self.count = 0


    """
    method: This method returns list of tweets and meta data back
    input: 
            Object: scan_twittosphere object
    output:
            Dictionary list: Twitter dictionary list element containing
                Integer: Tweet id
                Float: lr tweet score
                String: Keyword of tweet

    """

    def stream_score_tweets(self,scan_twittosphere_obj):
        tweets_list = []
        '''
        search UserFactory
        '''
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            self.count = 0

            if self.count < self.config.max_tweet:
                scan_twittosphere_obj.stream_tweets(keyword,'tweet')
                tweets_list = self.add_tweets(keyword,tweets_list)
            else:
                return tweets_list
        return tweets_list


    """
    method: This method adds a tweet to the list from the mongodb database and updates the 
            new user allocated to the tweet
    input: 
            String: keyword
            String List: tweets dictionary

    output:
            String List: tweets dictionary

    """
    def add_tweets(self,keyword,tweets_list):

        for tweet in self.MongoObj.getTweetFactoryCol().find({'keyword':keyword}):

            tweet_dict = {}
            user_list = []
            if len(tweet['user_list']) <= self.config.max_user_list:

                    user_list = tweet['user_list']

                    if self.screen_name not in user_list:

                        user_list.append(self.screen_name)

                        self.MongoObj.getTweetFactoryCol().update({'tweet_id':tweet['tweet_id']}, {'$set': {'user_list':user_list}})
                        tweet_dict['tweet_id'] = tweet['tweet_id']
                        tweet_dict['twittalikescore'] = tweet['twittalikescore']
                        tweet_dict['keyword'] = keyword
                        self.addFavorite(tweet["tweet_id"])
                        tweets_list.append(tweet_dict)
                        self.count += 1
            if self.count >= self.config.max_tweet:
                return tweets_list      
        return tweets_list  


    """
    method: This method adds a tweet to the favorites section of the user
    input: 
            Integer: Tweet id

    output:
            Boolean: True or (False in case of exception)

    """            
    def addFavorite(self,tweet_id):
        if self.mode_auto_favorite == 1:
            try:
                self.api.create_favorite(tweet_id)
                return True
            except:
                return False

    """
    method: This method returns list of users and meta data back
    input: 
            Object: scan_twittosphere object
    output:
            Dictionary list: Twitter dictionary list containing
                Integer: User id
                Float: lr tweet score
                String: Keyword of User

    """
    def stream_score_users(self,scan_twittosphere_obj):
        users_list = []
        '''
        search UserFactory
        '''
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            self.count = 0
            #debugger.info(keyword,self.config.log)

            if self.count < self.config.max_users:
                scan_twittosphere_obj.stream_tweets(keyword,'user')
                users_list = self.add_users(keyword,users_list)
            else:
                return users_list
        return users_list

    """
    method: This method adds a user to the list from the mongodb database and updates the 
            new lr twitter user allocated to the recommended twitter user
    input: 
            String: keyword
            String List: users  dictionary

    output:
            String List: users dictionary

    """
    def add_users(self,keyword,users_list):
        for user in self.MongoObj.getUserFactoryCol().find({'keyword':keyword}):

            user_dict = {}
            user_reco_list = []
            if len(user['user_list']) <= self.config.max_user_list:

                    user_reco_list = user['user_list']

                    if self.screen_name not in user_reco_list:                       
                        user_reco_list.append(self.screen_name)
                        self.MongoObj.getUserFactoryCol().update({'user_id':user['user_id']}, {'$set': {'user_list':user_reco_list}})
                        user_dict['user_id'] = user['user_id']
                        user_dict['twittalikescore'] = user['twittalikescore']
                        user_dict['keyword'] = keyword
                        self.addFavorite(user["tweet_id"])
                        users_list.append(user_dict)
                        self.count += 1

            if self.count >= self.config.max_users:
                return users_list     
        return users_list
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with having methods longer than 10 lines. If there are no reusable elements in those methods then the only reason to break them into more methods is aesthetic (and can also improve readability if you name your methods well).

A couple of comments on the rest of the code:

**Imports**

```
from scan_twittosphere import *
from tweets import *
```

Try to avoid `import *` whenever possible. It clutters the namespace and makes the code much less readable to people who do not already know the libraries you are using well. If you are using many methods or classes from these modules use:

```
import scan_twittosphere as stw
import tweets as tw
```

and if you are just using a few bit and pieces:

```
from scan_twittosphere import <names of>,<functions>,<or classes>
from tweets import <names of>,<functions>,<or classes>
```

**Docstrings**

While your docstrings are nicely laid out and readable, they should reside inside the method, function or class they pertain to, not above. See here for the appropriate PEP257 docstring conventions, http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/.

**New-style classes**

New-style classes (https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) should inherit from `object`. i.e.

```
class filter_tweets:
```

should be:

```
class filter_tweets(object):
```

**Naming conventions**

So generally it good to follow PEP8 guidelines (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming of variables, functions, classes, etc.

Each word in a class name should be capitalised and there should be no underscores:

```
class filter_tweets(object):
```

goes to:

```
class FilterTweets(object):
```

also to quote PEP8:

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide
>   is important. Consistency within a project is more important.
>   Consistency within one module or function is most important.

This applies to your `addFavorite` method, which should really be `add_favorite`. Speaking of this method:

```
def addFavorite(self,tweet_id):
    if self.mode_auto_favorite == 1:
        try:
            self.api.create_favorite(tweet_id)
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

you aren't using those return values anywhere. Also it may be worth catching the certain errors that might be caused by your code, like invalid types for `tweet_id` (as python is dynamically typed). This isn't a big issue, but it can often help with debugging.

All in all the code looks pretty good, with nice documentation and (even more importantly) descriptive variable names.

Comment: No worries, it's easy to review well laid out code.